# Android Studios failed to read key from store. Invalid key store format

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3, keystore, android-keystore

I am encountering an issue where if I were to create an entirely new key store via android studios and attempting to use the newly created key store to create a aab file it will result in the error **"Failed to read key from store. Invalid key store format"**

However, if I were to create the key store by changing directory to my java directory where keytool.exe is located and running in the CMD. I will have no issues generating the aab file.

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin`
2. `keytool -genkey -v -keystore testing-today-only.keystore -alias today-test -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Why is this the case? Why isn't the key store generated from Android Studios working? The project is an ionic project if it matters.